# How to read a pdf file saved in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully uploaded pdf files to the database but now when I am trying to read the files I'm getting issue "Failed to load PDF" when I click on the link.

```
<a href="pdf.php<?php echo '?PDF='.$PDF;?> " target="_blank" ></i> View Attachment</a>
$PDF = $_GET['PDF'];
$file = './upload/PDF'.$PDF;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Description: inline; filename="' .$file. '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: paste your code in your question.

Comment: What you posted does not access adatabse

Comment: Now I think My Post is Looks Good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i see some things that you shouldn't do. First you shouldn't use unfiltered GET variables in a string that load something from your filesystem. So filter them first. I would suggest to read the security documentation.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.php

The next thing i think you forgot a `/` in your string.

```
$file = './upload/PDF/'.$PDF;
```

you should take it to a subfolder for better understanding.

And the last thing if you have a file and you try to return them you have to return them as stream. Something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("./upload/PDF/yourname.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=nameofyour.pdf");
echo $data;
```

Then you can return them and your browser can open them. And you don't use a database in your post. You only try to open an attachment. So it would be much easier to set a very simple link to your PDF file and generate only the URL from your database.

Comment: Ohh i get my problem i miss the slash /... Thanks All